# Plotly JS: stacked area diagramm is not stacked

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly

this is how my plotly diagram looks like:

[image]

but it is not stacked. The lines are just overlayed...

this is my angular implementation:

```
diag.timeseries.forEach(timeSerie => {
          let plot: any = {
            y: timeSerie.values,
            name: timeSerie.name,
            marker: { color: timeSerie.color }
          };
          if (timeSerie.name == null || timeSerie.name == "") {
            plot.name = timeSerie.id;
          }
          if (timeSerie.type === 'boxplot') {
            plot.type = 'box';

          } else if (timeSerie.type === 'stackedsplinearea') {
            plot.type = 'scatter'
            plot.fill = 'tozeroy';
            plot.x = diag.timestamps;
          } else {
            plot.mode = 'lines';
            plot.x = diag.timestamps;
          }

          if (timeSerie.yAxis === '2') {
            plot.yaxis = "y2";
          }

          if (!this.showZeroValues && timeSerie.values.every(v => v === 0) && diag.timeseries.some(ts => ts.type !== 'bar')) {
            plot.visible = false;
          } else {
            plot.visible = true;
          }

          graph.data = [
            ...graph.data,
            plot
          ];

        });
```

I do not really understand how to modify the code to create a diagram where the traces(plots) are stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a [`stackgroup`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/scatter/#scatter-stackgroup).

> **`stackgroup`** : Set several scatter traces (on the same subplot) to the same
> stackgroup in order to add their y values (or their x values if
> `orientation` is "h").
> **If blank or omitted this trace will not be
> stacked.**
> Stacking also turns `fill` on by default, using "tonexty" ("tonextx") if `orientation` is "v" ("h") and sets the default `mode` to "lines" irrespective of point count.

As mentioned in the doc, if you want to be explicit for the `fill` parameter you should also set it accordingly.

```
if (timeSerie.type === 'stackedsplinearea') {
  plot.type = 'scatter';
  plot.stackgroup = 'one';
  plot.fill = 'tonexty';
  plot.x = diag.timestamps;
}
```